# Changing the properties values on markup code

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am working with some bootstrap components on a small template website using ASP.NET.  I am wondering if there was a way to change the values of the Markup code using the code behind (C#)
Here is my markup code

```
        <small>Units Completed </small>
           <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%">
                      <span class="sr-only">95% Complete</span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
```

For example if wanted to change the ***aria-valuenow*** or the ***aria-valuenow*** in the code behind then how would I go about doing it.  I have tried assigning the progress bar an ID but that doesn't work.  Thanks in advance and sorry if I seem vague

Comment: have you heard of model binding? If not how about ajax

Comment: I have no clue what they are.  I am very new to web form development, sorry :(

Comment: Model binding is not there in web forms. However you can make ajax call on page load and then manipulate these values based on result using javascript

Comment: Would you be willing to give me a link or example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you asking for, then the answer is yes you can by adding a render tags in HTML code such as this example

in code behind

```
protected String Vall()
{
    return "95";
}
```

and then in the html you can render as

```
<small>Units Completed </small>
       <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%=Vall()%>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"   >
                  <span class="sr-only">95% Complete</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

for this case you can use the tag <%=method() %> to render in value from code behind in case you have some logic to fill this value